# Check engine light error

Tags: cel, buick, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor, lacrosse

My 06 Buick LaCrosse 3.8L has a check engine light that says that the MAP has a low voltage, so I checked the air filter. It was clean, then I changed out the MAP and the check engine light went off the next day and then the lcd screen said check gas cap even though the gas cap and the seal on it was tight and secure...

But one day later the MAP came back up saying low voltage, any ideas.

This MAP sits right on top of the PCV, the PCV was clear. I could blow through it, are these two things closely related, I mean where and why am I getting a low voltage if the flow is clear

Comment: What is the OBD2 code?

Comment: It's like p0107 I belive

Comment: 4 causes, bad MAP, bad wiring, big vacuum leak or burnt valve, bad ECU.

Comment: A vacuum leak could cause a MAP sensor to read low voltage ? Could it be a leak in the fuel supply line causing it ?

Comment: ECM expects to see an operation range on MAP voltage, 1-5v, anything that causes the MAP to be outside that range (above or below) (which the MAP can do) will set that code. No, fuel has nothing to do with MAP (manifold absolute pressure).